# Given $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ with $||f||_1 < \infty$, is it true that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} ||f||_1 - f(x) \, dx = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, absolute-value

According to my intuition so far, the answer should be yes, hinging very important on the assumption that $||f||_1 < \infty$.

To speak very roughly, if the $L^1$ norm of $f$ is finite, it seems to make sense to me that the integral over the reals of the $L^1$ norm of $f$ minus $f$ should come out to be zero, as its fluctuations about its norm should "cancel out".

When I try to formalize this conjecture, however,

$$\int_\mathbb{R} ||f||_1 - f(x) \, dx$$

is not an integral I can see how to evaluate.

Is my conjecture correct? How might one go about proving or disproving it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not true at all. As a matter of fact, if $\|f\|_1\not= 0$, the integral diverges!

For example, consider $f(x)=\chi_{(0,1)}$. Then $\|f(x)\|_1=1$ and

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 1-\chi_{(0,1)}dx=2\int_1^{\infty}1dx$$

Comment: Counterexamples are usually obvious in retrospect, aren't they? I slapped myself on the forehead. Thank you for the counterexample.

Comment: The funny thing is, as wrong as your conjecture is (sorry!), I totally understand the intuition. I wonder if there is something there...@user169845

Comment: I wonder too, because something about this bugs me. The intuition I was working off of was that as the $L^1$ norm is taken over the real line, the "deviations from the norm" would "cancel out". When I was thinking about it, I was thinking of functions that are nonzero on the entire real line; in retrospect, my assumption would also, at least, also need the assumption that the function is nonnegative. I do notice that your counterexample has compact support; however, I am not knowledgeable enough to gauge whether that is of any real significance.

Comment: Compact support, or no compact support, it doesn't matter. What the issue is, is that $\|f\|_1$ is just some number. So you're integrating a number minus some fluff (since $f(x)$ is integrable, it doesn't matter what it is, you'll diverge).What you want to think about is $m(x)-f(x)$ where $m(x)$ is the mean of the function up to point $x$. Or another thing you can do, is consider a finite measure space and consider $\|f(x)\|_1/\mu(X)$. @user169845

Comment: Right, I was thinking of $||f_1||$ as the "mean", which was wrong. If one were given a function and its mean value over an interval, one might expect that the integral of that function's mean minus that function, over that same interval, might be zero - at least, that's where my thoughts were. Again, though, your counterexample proved that "intuition" wrong. I'm trying to put my finger on where my reasoning was wrong (past considering the $L^1$ norm as an "average", which is clearly wrong).

Comment: Your main issue is that the mean is $\|f(x)\|_1/\mu(X)$, so if $\mu(X)=\infty$, you have some issues @user169845

Comment: I'm not familiar with that notation - what is $|L^1|$, for one? - but yes, I clearly have at least a handful of misunderstandings here. I'll hit the textbook. Thank you for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry, I just wrote down the think incorrectly. I meant $f(x)$ lol. $\mu(X)$ is the measure or "length" of $X$, in this case $\mathbb{R}$. @user169845